# count independent values in different columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, count, percentage, na

I have a data frame with several different columns and I want to get the frequency of different variables, check how the frequency of data changes depending on a parameter or two and compare the changes from the known or available `ids` to the missing `ids` where I have `NA`.

The objects `Id` is always known but there are cases where `rq_ind` is missing and those are interesting.

Basically I need to get the Nieseln area class of available object / Nielsen area of all ( missing and not missing objects ( which is the `inq_onr_id==NA` but their `object_id` is available)

```
    rq_id , rq_object_id , inq_onr_id,  inq_id,  Nielsen class, age_class,   revnue-class , employee_class                              
    157467  19750137    19750137    NA  3   3   4   2
    157467  19750137    19750137    NA  3   3   4   2
    423008  19750137    NA          NA  3   3   4   2   
    423008  19750137    NA          NA  3   3   4   2   
    157467  19750137    NA          NA  3   2   4   2   

    B1_fourth3month19short<-data.frame(rq_id,
                                     rq_object_id,
                                      inq_onr_id,inq_id,
                                      nielsen_area,Employeeclass)
```

All info are factors in principle.

What I want to take out is to find out how the `fre(rq_object_id)` vs Nieslen area changes in the case where the `onr-id` is missing vs where the `onr _id` is available.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data frame like this : df <- data.frame("rq_id" = 1, "rq_object" = 2, ...) and also an example of the desire output so we can precisely bring a solution to your need.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is `table`:

```
out <- table(df[,c(2,3,5)],useNA = "ifany")
```

where `df` is your initial data frame.

Output:

```
> out
, , Nielsen_class = 3

            inq_onr_id
rq_object_id 19750137 <NA>
    19750137        2    3
```

To get the percent of each row, do the following:

```
out.percent <- prop.table(table(df[,c(2,3,5)],useNA = "ifany"))*100
```

Output in percent:

```
> out.percent
, , Nielsen_class = 3

            inq_onr_id
rq_object_id 19750137 <NA>
    19750137       40   60
```

Comment: ok that helps and how do i get percentage on my e.g onr-id ( how many are there ) with grouping on nielsen area as an example ?

Comment: do you mean here onr_id is 2/5*100 percent?

Comment: i just get errors cuz my data is about 8 million datasets and its saying :  Error in table(B1_first3month[, c(2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18)],  : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Comment: Try separating your data into manageable chunks and running this code on those subsets. Hope you understand this is already out of scope of this particular question.